# How hide icon in TabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I create a tabNavigator using `createStackNavigator` my code is following:

```javascript
const ArticlesStack = createStackNavigator({
  Articles: ArticlesScreen,
},
{
  cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' },
});

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
  Profile: ProfileScreen,
},
{
  cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' },
});

const ArticleStack = createStackNavigator({
  Article: ArticleScreen,
},
{
  cardStyle: { backgroundColor: '#fff' },
});

ArticlesStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Articles',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused = {focused}
      name = {
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-link${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-link'
      }
    />
  ),
};

ArticleStack.navigationOptions = {
  header: null,
};

ProfileStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused = {focused}
      name = {
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-options${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-options'
      }
    />
  ),
};

bottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  ArticlesStack,
  ArticleStack,
  ProfileStack,
});

export default createSwitchNavigator({
  Main: bottomTabNavigator,
});
```

And my TabBar:

[image]

But i want to hide de ArticleStack title in my TabBar.

What i have to do?

Comment: Will no apear, but also will no get acessable. I need acess de articlestack without tabbar

Comment: Do you want to just hide it or remove it completely? Why can't you just delete `ArticleStack` from `createBottomTabNavigator` where it is defined?